# Choose file with browser to :read into buffer

Tags: filesystem

I want to `:r[ead]` a file into current buffer, and the file should be picked with the browser (that opens automatically e.g. when trying to `:e[dit]` a directory.

`:e ~/.vim/` opens a file browser in the ~/.vim/ directory, but `:r ~/.vim/` just complains about ~/.vim not being a file.

`:h browse` seems to imply that `:bro r ~/.vim/` should open a bowser to find a file to read, but it too doesn't.

I'm running

> VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Feb  9 2016 10:20:47)
>
> Included patches: 1-1294
>
> Compiled by Arch Linux

Comment: `:browse :r ~/.vim` works just fine for me.

Comment: Huh. For me it returns http://i.imgur.com/V8Yj1t7.png

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt On Linux, it's only available when used with the GUI.

Comment: I thought we are talking about the gui here.

Answer (score 1):

When I try your command `:bro r ~/.vim/`, I have the following error:

```
E338: Sorry, no file browser in console mode
```

There may be a native and simpler way, but assuming you use the default file browser netrw, then you could try the following code:

```
augroup custom_netrw
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType netrw nnoremap <buffer> e :<C-U>call <SID>ReadNetrw()<CR>
augroup END

function! s:GetFileNames(first, last) abort
    " Grab lines between first and last
    let l:files = getline(a:first, a:last)

    " If some of them are from the banner, remove them
    call filter(l:files, 'v:val !~# "^\" "')
    " If some of them are a directory, an executable, a fifo or a socket
    " they end up with one of the symbols: /*|=
    " Remove them
    call filter(l:files, 'v:val !~# "[/*|=]$"')
    " Remove the text after the @ symbol (link):
    call map(l:files, "substitute(v:val, '@\\t.*$', '', '')")

    " Prepend the path of the current directory in front of each filename
    return map(l:files, 'b:netrw_curdir . "/" . v:val')
endfunction

function! s:ReadNetrw() abort
    " Get the name of the file on the current line, and on following ones if
    " a count was hit before the mapping (i.e. if v:count1 != 1)
    let l:files = s:GetFileNames(line('.'), line('.') - 1 + v:count1)

    " Go back to alternate buffer before reading
    b#

    for i in range(len(l:files))
        " Read each file
        execute 'read ' . l:files[i]
        " After each insertion, move the cursor at the end of it
        ']
    endfor
endfunction
```

It installs a buffer-local mapping on the `e` key (`r` seems already taken by netrw to reverse the sort order) which calls the function `ReadNetrw()`.

If you open netrw with `:e ~/.vim/` and then hit `e` on a file, its contents should be read in the alternate buffer (which should be the buffer from which you opened netrw).
The mapping accepts a count, meaning that if you hit `3e`, it should read the file under the cursor as well as the 2 following ones.